# How to install the pthreads PHP extension on Debian 9

Tags: php, debian, pthreads

Surprisingly, I can't find an answer anywhere. I need help to install the `pthreads` PHP extension on Debian 9 with PHP 7.3 installed.
If I write `php -v`, I get the following:

```
PHP 7.3.6-1+0~20190531112735.39+stretch~1.gbp6131b7 (cli) (built: May 31 2019 11:27:35) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.6, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.6-1+0~20190531112735.39+stretch~1.gbp6131b7, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

I tried to download the .tgz file form pecl.php.net, extract it, put it in `/etc/php/7.3/fpm/ext` (I created the `ext` directory) and define the `extension_dir` as that directory in `php.ini`.
Then I wrote in the `php.ini` file `extension=/etc/php/7.3/fpm/ext/pthreads-3.1.6` and I rebooted my server.

If I write `php -m`, I still not see the `pthreads` extension.

Comment: As far as I know you have to compile PHP 7.x yourself with pthread support enabled to get this to work